# R shiny: Unwanted reactivity when filling in a form that hints a user and supports an autofill function

Tags: r, forms, shiny, autofill, shiny-reactivity

I'm building a small form app in Shiny that should handle two usecases:

1. The user fills-in a form from top-to-bottom and is hinted with
   several options during entering.
2. The user hits a button that autofills the form,
   the user can alter the fields before submission.

Unfortunately I can't find out how to suppress the reactivity that I need in usecase 1, while realizing usecase 2.

I think that this is a common problem, but I haven't managed to find a working solution with functions like `lsolate()` or using the `event_env` en `handle_env` parameters in `observeEvent()`.
[image: Suppress reactivity in a form app]

The following code demonstrates a simplification of the problem that I have with supressing reactivity:

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

    titlePanel("Try to suppress reactivity"),

    verticalLayout(
        mainPanel(
            textInput('inp1', 'inputbox1', value = 'initial value, change triggers inputbox2'),
            textInput('inp2', 'inputbox2', value = 'initial value'),
            actionButton('btn1', 'should only trigger change of inputbox1'),
            actionButton('reset', 'should reset both boxes to initial state')
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

    observeEvent(input$inp1,
                 updateTextInput(session, inputId = 'inp2', value = 'triggered')
                 , ignoreInit = TRUE)

    observeEvent(input$btn1, updateTextInput(session, inputId = 'inp1', value = 'triggered using btn1'), ignoreInit = TRUE)

    observeEvent(input$reset,{
        updateTextInput(session, inputId = 'inp1', value = 'initial value')
        updateTextInput(session, inputId = 'inp2', value = 'initial value')
    }, ignoreInit = TRUE)

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use this

```
 observeEvent(input$inp1,{
    if (!(input$inp1 %in% c("initial value","triggered using btn2")) )
      updateTextInput(session, inputId = 'inp2', value = 'triggered')
  }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
```

Comment: While `observeEvent(input$inp1,{... }, suspended = TRUE)` is another option, I am not sure that it meets your needs.

Comment: ```r
observeEvent(input$inp1,{
if (!(input$inp1 %in% c("initial value","initial value, change triggers inputbox2","triggered using btn1"))) 
updateTextInput(session, inputId = 'inp2', value = 'triggered')
} , ignoreInit = TRUE) ```

works, but it forces me to repeat all options in the condition. For this simple case it wouldn't be a big point, but since the hints are fetched from a server this won't be the best option I think.

I'm trying to get the suspend solution working. It seems appropriate, but I can't manage to resume afterwards.

Comment: suspended= TRUE option is not working as expected for me too.